# Komodo Edit and SSH Private Keyfile in Pageant for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, komodoedit, pageant

I would like to use Komodo Edit to edit files on my Ubuntu [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance (running Django).

According to this [Old Nabble from 2008](http://old.nabble.com/remote-server-and-ssh-key-td18117059.html) (oh boy) Komodo Edit should support SSH authentication via Pageant keyfiles.

So, I imported my .pem keyfile in PuTTYGen, converted it to .ppk (no password) and loaded it into Pageant. I am able to use PuTTY just fine to SSH into my instance.

I can also use Notepad++'s reasonable NppFTP with the AWS instance by adding the server and using the original .pem file directly (NppFTP doesn't seem to use pageant.)

However, I would like to use Komodo Edit, so I loaded up Komodo Edit, went to **Edit** -> **Preferences** --> **Servers**, and put in my Public DNS address (ec2-174-129-xxx-xxx.compute-2.amazonaws.com) and my username which was required ('ubuntu').

When attempting to connect, however, I get a "Javascript Application Error: ''" (a seemingly empty error) from Komodo Edit. I can't find any sort of logs or console to watch the handshake (Notepad's NppFTP plugin had a nice one.)

Obviously I can just use NppFTP but I would like to get this feature working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use putty 0.60. According to [this site](http://community.activestate.com/node/6947) there's an incompatibility between the versions you are using.